# Can't install composer - the json extension is missing

Tags: php, json, ubuntu, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer on my Ubuntu 13.10 machine but the following error occurs:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The json extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-json
```

`php --version` gives me `PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2 (cli)` so I think it should have the json extension installed.

Comment: issue the command 'php -m' then please paste the list of modules installed (json should be one of them)

Comment: **[PHP Modules]**
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
libxml
mbstring
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

**[Zend Modules]**
Zend OPcache

Comment: forgive me, I'm a CentOS admin primarily and only have a couple ubuntu servers that are pretty static. I believe you want to do the following though: sudo apt-get install php5-json

Comment: php7 centos                                                                                                                        

    sudo yum install php70u-json

Answer (score 48, accepted):

just install the module:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

---

**EDIT - Reason:**

See [Heanzo Beanzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2292766/heanzo-beanzo) Comment:

> It has been removed in recent packages due to a license conflict  [see
>   bug on php.net](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63520).

Comment: That works thanks. But isn't the json extension supposed to be bundled and compiled into PHP by default?

Comment: the core of php is rather small, all is grouped in modules. if you compile from source, many of this modules (like json) are selected by default. but it seems the package maintainer want to give the user more control over what he wants to install. this is good in most cases.

Comment: It has been removed in recent packages due to a license conflict (see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63520).

Comment: If php-json were a dependency of php-common, everyone would have installed it while upgrading to 13.10..It wasted enough of my time to file a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1280030

Comment: and the whole reason why.. cause he thinks he is funny... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hCimLnIsDA

Comment: How do you verify it's installed or not?